# React children id is being incremented by 1

Tags: reactjs

The children id is somehow incremented

Parent:

```
render() {
const { matches } = this.state;
return (
  <div className='admin-match-detail'>
   {
      this.props.id
    }
    {
      matches
      .filter((match, id) => id === this.props.id)
      .map((match) =>  (
        <MatchItem key={match.id} id={match.id} match={match} isEdit />
      ))
  }
  </div>
)
```

}

Children:

```
const MatchItem = ({ match, isEdit, id }) => {
  const { HomeTeamName, HomeScore, AwayTeamName, AwayScore} = match;

  return (
    <div className='match-item'>
        <div className='final-score-container'>
          <div className='team'>
            {match.id}
```

Somehow matchId in children prop is somehow incremented by 1 once its clicked.
I've double checked parent's this.props.id and it was 1 and once its passed to matchItem it got incremented.
Do you guys know why it happens and how I can fix it? e.g. .find()?

Comment: Nothing in this code increments anything as far as I can tell, so I don't see that enough information is provided. Please add a [mcve] which can be executed to show the behavior (show all relevant props). Thanks.